# Is there a notification on windows phone that disappears after seconds?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, toast

Is there something like Androids toast message for windows phone ?

I just want to notify the user somehow if my BackgroundAudioPlayer is at the end of the playlist or couldn't find a song. 
It should also only appear if the user is currently inside the application, so something like "ShellToast" doesn't work.

Comment: If it only appears when the user is inside your app, you could create a custom control that displays itself for a set amount of time before becoming hidden. I don't know of any built-in controls that do that, but you could customise the `popup` control.

Comment: use the notificationcontrol of the NorthernLights WP7 toolkit (on codeplex) pretty basic but it works.