# Windows phone and Android toasts

Tags: android, windows-phone-7

Does Windows Phone 7 have an analogue of Toasts from Android?

The Windows Phone toasts I've seen only relate to push notifications.

Comment: Similar question here i think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625620/is-there-a-notification-on-windows-phone-that-disappears-after-seconds I would create a custom popup object and display/dismiss it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display toasts in your application without using push notifications, you can use Toast Prompt control provided in the Coding4Fun toolkit: http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/